# Package a unix executable within a MacOS app

Tags: swift, unix, macos-sierra

My organization has built a signal simulation tool that has a very large c++ codebase. Currently, a user has to download the entire codebase, then run cmake to get the executable. The executable itself is then run from the command line. An xml file containing configuration data is passed as an argument.

Essentially, the utility (called twang) is run with the following command:

```
./twang --xml config.xml
```

Everyone in our organization uses macs, so I would like to distribute the tool as a self contained app. Ideally the executable and the xml file would be contained within the app. A GUI would allow a user to easily edit the xml file, then run the executable with said xml file passed as an argument. This app will only be distributed within our organization, so it doesn't need to abide by App Store rules. So far, I haven't found any way embed a pre-compiled executable within a swift app, and then pass arguments using swift. Furthermore, the executable sends data to a peripheral that is attached via ethernet. Is it possible for a compiled executable to be packaged and run within an app, yet have the same access to peripheral devices as an executable that is run from the command line?

Comment: Search for NSTask.

Comment: You may also have to look at Apple's docs relative to `Bundle`s to seal things into an app.

Comment: Also, take a look at Helper Apps. Helper Apps are (typically) standalone executables bundled within application itself. You can also prepare custom dmg file if you are working within your organization only. This way, you can easily put there, whatever you like.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm in similar situation now.